# Popover on dynamically created element in Angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

plunker example  http://plnkr.co/edit/xbAkED?p=preview

if an element is created dynamically and not available in the view on load, popover won't work.

How can i make it work?

```
<script>
  angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
  var testController = ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = 'test';

  $('<button id="needsPopover" style="margin-left:10px;" popover-title="1. Lowest" popover-template="template1"  popover-placement="bottom" popover-trigger="mouseenter">Dynamicaly Created Button</button>').appendTo($('body'));
  }];


</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to compile it using angulars `$compile` service:

```
var $button = $('<button class="btn" id="needsPopover" style="margin-left:10px;" popover-title="1. Lowest" popover-template="template1"  popover-placement="bottom" popover-trigger="mouseenter">Dynamicaly Created Button</button>');
$compile($button) ($scope);
$button.appendTo($('body'));
```

[See Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mYWlT1v9zNBX3VRMjYAN?p=preview)